# How to set flushpackets=on in apache FCGI only for selected url

Tags: php, apache, proxy, httpd.conf

I'm trying to configure my Apache web server to use the `flushpackets=on` with php-fpm FCGI backend, but I want this setting to apply only to a specific URL.

My current php-fpm config is:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    <Proxy "fcgi://localhost" enablereuse=on flushpackets=on max=10>
       ProxySet timeout=100
    </Proxy>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

This sets flushpackets on for all request, but I want it have enabled only for a specific url, like  `/endpoint_1/`

Answer (score 1):

To apply `flushpackets=on` only to a specific URL, use the `<Location>`

Like this :

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost/general"
    </FilesMatch>

    <Proxy "fcgi://localhost/endpoint_1">
        ProxySet enablereuse=on
        ProxySet flushpackets=on
        ProxySet max=10
        ProxySet timeout=100
    </Proxy>

    <Proxy "fcgi://localhost/general">
        ProxySet enablereuse=on
        ProxySet flushpackets=off
        ProxySet max=10
        ProxySet timeout=100
    </Proxy>

    <Location /endpoint_1/>
        ProxyPass "fcgi://localhost/endpoint_1"
        ProxyPassReverse "fcgi://localhost/endpoint_1"
    </Location>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass "fcgi://localhost/general"
        ProxyPassReverse "fcgi://localhost/general"
    </Location>

  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This was my initial idea, but it does not work. Apache/2.4.37 fails with error: Proxy not allowed in <Location> context.

Comment: I update the code

Comment: not sure I understand your idea of having two <Proxy> directives, and how that would apply to SetHandler in FilesMatch

Comment: <Proxy> Directives: These define settings for two different FastCGI proxies:
fcgi://localhost/endpoint_1: This proxy has flushpackets=on, which means it will flush the output buffer after each packet. This can be useful for streaming responses.
fcgi://localhost/general: This proxy has flushpackets=off, which means it will buffer the output and send it all at once.

Comment: yes, replace fcgi://localhost by fcgi://localhost/general in FilesMatch

Comment: OK, now that makes sense. will try

Comment: Location is set in incorrect order, and thats why we do not recommend to mix proxypass and location, because they are interpreted in different order. Location should be defined most global path first, while proxypass should be defined most specific path first. Also always make sure to match trailing slashes.